# Confusion about Memory deallocation in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm having some confusion about memory de-allocation in C++. I have a structure

```
struct Node{
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

and I declare a pointer of Node type as:

`struct Node* myNode = new Node;`

Now if I do a `delete myNode` does it also de-allocates the `left` and `right` pointer inside `myNode`? If it doesn't, wouldn't it be very tedious if we have a lot of pointers inside `Node` type and will be very difficult to write code without memory leakage?

Comment: free() releases the memory block pointed by myNode. It doesn't care about left and right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it wont destruct or deallocate them. However, for such cases you can write a destructor:

```
~Node()
{
    delete left;
    delete right;
}
```

An even better approach would be to use smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Although it makes the code more clear, checking for null pointers is unnecessary. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Comment: Checking for null makes the code less clear. Are we working around a bug in a custom allocator? Why is that line of code there? It would disturb me to see that in our codebase.

Comment: @Xenotoad Sorry I wasnt aware of the fact that `delete` checks for nullptrs, I will remove the if clauses

Comment: even though I've deleted the myNode pointer using "delete myNode", I can still call "myNode->left" without any error. What I understand is if memory is freed using delete, a try to use it again will cause segmentation fault. but that's not the case I'm seeing here.

Comment: @azizulfahim Its undefined behaviour. Simply dont do it. However for an explanation: `myNode->left` will only dereference `myNode` and not `left`. Notice that even after delete `myNode` still has the old value and thus points to the old memory location.. If your lucky the memory region `myNode` points to is still "valid" in terms of page protection. As OS usually dont overwrite unallocated memory with zeros (as it is unneccessary), the dereference might still work as the memory hasnt been overwriten yet by other code.

Comment: @Paranaix thanks for you valuable comment. so what should be my approach in scenario like this when I want to delete a dynamically allocated memory location so that no one else can use it?

Comment: @azizulfahim Just like in my answere?